# database migration with data already in the database in production

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, migration, production

I don't know much about migrations, but this is a specific question I'm not sure how to answer.

In production, how can one change the database format/schema when there is already user data in there? (Is the answer different for our Meteor app on MongoDB vs our master Postgres database?) Basically, if you write new code that introduces a new field, and new code that expects that new field to be present, then the system will not work when pulling data from the database that was there prior to the changeover.

For Mongo at least, a possible solution is to write a script to update the database layout with the data in it, but I wonder if this is too error prone for a production database, and infeasible when you just don't have the necessary information (like if you didn't collect a certain info field from the user before.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Postgres expert, but in the classic relational DB case, you alter your schema and set a default for the field if it is not populated (NULL, other).  Then, usually, you write your code to deal with the null/default value in the field or you do a mass update to populate the field appropriately.

With MongoDB you can do the same thing, but there is no need for the (potentially expensive) `ALTER` command to change schema or a default setting, you can simply add the field when appropriate (as you add or update documents for other purposes).

Essentially, you lazily add the field and don't worry about the documents that don't have it.  Instead of writing code to deal with the default/null value, you write code that deals with the absence of the field (for example, add a default value if not present).  It's a subtle but important difference if you are going to do this regularly or if schema changes are particularly expensive.  This [Craigslist presentation](http://www.mongodb.com/presentations/mongodb-and-craigslists-data-storage-evolution) (old but good) gives a great real world example of just this type of thing (and there are subsequent ones talking about lessons learned over time too.

Comment: +1, but I would like to add that it sometimes can be easier in MongoDB to run a job to update all documents than to add code to deal with both the old and the new document structure, especially when you make considerable changes to the way you organize your data. But when your database is already large you can often not do this without a planned downtime while an on-access migration can be done seamlessly.

Answer (score 1):

As for Postgres database migration: You might want to have a look at [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org). It is feature rich, easy to user, migration scriptlets are saved with the source code.